# Using local .ttf in vscode extension webview

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to load a .ttf file into my vscode extension's webview panel. However, I can't seem to understand what url I should be pointing to. My current attempt is:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: myfont;
    src:url("vscode-resource:{fontlocation}")
}
body{
}
```

I then replace `{fontlocation}` with the result of `__dirname + path.sep + "myfont.ttf"`, aka the absolute location of the `myfont.ttf` file, which is in the root of my extension folder.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Webviews require the full file path with `vscode-resource`, so an example uri would look: `vscode-resource:/Users/matb/fonts/CosmicSands.tff`. Also make sure that that resulting path is included in the webviews's `localResourceRoots`. Please share your extension source if that is still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per usual, the fix was embarrassingly stupid. The problem is that I was running this on windows, and css doesn't like the default path separator (`\`). So a simple fix is to use `__dirname.split(String.fromCharCode(92)).join("/") + "/myfont.ttf"`.

Once in the css, the path should look like this:

`src:url(vscode-resource:C:/Users/me/source/repos/vscodeextension/out/myfont.ttf)`

I didn't even need to add anything to the webview's `localRessourceRoots`, seeing as the extension already has access to it's own install directory.